# Adding name to spring Resource object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi i am calling an endpoint that returns a spring resource with a byteArray in it and i need to pass this along to another endpoint that expects a spring Resource object.
But the incomming resource has no fileName. and the outgoing resource expects a filename to be present as it translates this to an emai attachment.

What is the best way to add a file name here?
I have been trying to copy the Resource to File and than read that file again into a new resource but it keeps telling met that the file does not exist in that location.

Comment: can you add some pseudo-code about this app.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller method you set the filename

```
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
            headers.setContentDispositionFormData(filename, filename);
            headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
```

and in the response entity

```
 return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentLength(fileLength)
                .body(resource);
```